# Simple local webpage to link to local pdf files

Tags: html, pdf, local

I generated many pdf files for my employer. There are so many that it is easy to get lost in the folder structure. I thought I could make this more user friendly for colleagues by generating a local webpage with drop down menus that link to the local pdf files, something like the following structure.

```
 Menu 1
           Option A
                     Subset i
                               Sub-subset i.a   ->   pdf file i.a (stored locally)
                               Sub-subset i.b   ->   pdf file i.b (stored locally)
                               Sub-subset i.c+d   ->   pdf files i.c and d (stored locally)
                     Subset ii   ->   pdf file ii (stored locally)
                     Subset iii   ->   pdf file iii (stored locally)
           Option B
                     Subset a   ->   pdf file a (stored locally)
                     Subset b   ->   pdf file b (stored locally)
           Option C
                     Subset 1   ->   pdf file 1 (stored locally)
                     Subset 2   ->   pdf file 2 (stored locally)
                     Subset 3   ->   pdf file 3 (stored locally)
 Menu 2
 Menu 3
```

Does anyone have tips or can recommend a template that is easy to edit? If possible, it would be ideal if a thumbnail or small version of the pdf could be shown, but more importantly, I would like it to be simple to edit, because I only know the basics of html and I do not need anything fancy. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You could automate creation of the page / menu via PHP. It will take you longer to build, but then it self-maintains. PHP is a server-side language (runs on your webserver) - which is what you need if you want to read through the folder structure, grab all the file names, parse them, and then output the HTML. This might be more than you want to do, but you should know of the option. *The final PHP code would probably be under 100 lines (or even under 50)*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I looked into this, but found it a bit complicated. Since I already know some basic html, I researched more html options via this website: (https://www.w3schools.com). This seems to be working out.